# Linking the `mail` and `sendmail` commands to Dovecot and Postfix

Tags: debian, email, postfix, sendmail, dovecot

I have recently set up my mail server with Debian 7.2 (Wheezy), Dovecot, and Postfix, as described in [this guide](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql). This is all working fine, and I have installed and configured Roundcube and Postfixadmin and got everything working nicely together.

What I would like to do now is link my normal user account to the `mail` and `sendmail` programs so that:

- `mail` reads the messages from the inbox for the e-mail account myuser@mydomain.com.
- `sendmail` sends messages from myuser@mydomain.com **and** it copies the sent e-mail into the "Sent Messages" folder of the mailbox of the user myuser@mydomain.com.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you talking about running those commands from the mail server, or from some other machine? If the latter, then what's the mail setup like on that other machine?

Comment: On the mail server.

Answer (score 1):

No, as point 1 cannot be done. `mail` doesn't do IMAP or POP3 as provided by Dovecot.

(Also once you link your home directory to `/usr/bin/mail` or `/usr/bin/sendmail` - can not do both - you not login anymore. do not do that)

Comment: Heirloom-mailx (one of the alternatives for `mail`) does both POP3 and IMAP.

Comment: I just checked and it turns out that my `mail` actually ends up running `heirloom-mailx`! How do I go about setting it up to use IMAP?